# How to make the background color of `x-show-tip` defined in `pos-tip.el` transparent?

Tags: frames, colors

I found the `flycheck-pos-tip` package uses a function defined in `pos-tip-show` which uses a built-in function: `x-show-tip`.

I want to change the background color of `x-show-tip` to be transparent.

There is a custom variable named `pos-tip-background-color` in the `pos-tip` package, how can I change this value to transparent? For example, the value of `pos-tip-background-color` is `#FF0000`, how can I change its alpha value to 50, so that I get a color of `RGBA(255,0,0,0.5)` if I use a CSS style value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a frame background transparent by changing the background *color*.  The `alpha` frame parameter is a separate parameter from `background-color`.

Function `x-show-tip` accepts an alist of tooltip frame parameters as argument.  If you are the caller of `x-show-tip` then you can add an `alpha` parameter and its value to the alist that you pass to `x-show-tip`.

Example:

```
(x-show-tip "HELLO" nil '((alpha . 20))) ; Show 80%-transparent tooltip
```

Here's an image showing the effect:

[image]

However, the call to `x-show-tip` in `pos-tip-show-no-propertize` is beyond your control in this regard: it hard-codes the parameter alist.

You could, however, advise or redefine `pos-tip-show-no-propertize`, giving yourself the possibility of modifying the parameters it passes to `x-show-tip`.

But `pos-tip.el` apparently doesn't offer any non-surgical way to do what you want.  You might want to consider requesting such a possibility from the maintainer of `pos-tip.el`.  S?he could, for example, add an optional argument that lets a caller pass the alist, defaulting to the alist that is currently hard-coded.

Comment: Hi, I found if I change the frame parameter using `(set-frame-parameter mframe 'alpha 0.8)` before `x-show-tip` is called, or append `(alpha . 0.8)` to the `parms` parameter of `x-show-tip`,the whole frame is made transparent, rather than only the tip being transparent. How to make the tip itself be transparent without affecting the whole frame?

Comment: Sorry, last message `0.8` just means `80`.

Comment: Sorry - I mistakenly said that the `FRAME` argument to `x-show-tip` was for the tooltip frame. I've edited the text to correct this, and I've provided an example that shows a tooltip with 80% transparency (20% opacity). HTH.

Comment: It seems not make the tip transparent. I paste the screenshot in the body of my quest. Thank you for your help, though.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe it depends what platform you're on. I added a screenshot. I'm using MS Windows.

Comment: Yep, I am using Mac. So this will be the problem of cross platform. Thanks a lot.